# Can i create 100,000+ collections in MongoDB?

Tags: database, mongodb, database-design, nosql

**Project Overview** : Large project where it deals with Multiple Retailers and Each Retailer will have Dynamic Entities and customers

**In Detail**: Project is related to Retailer Platform (Eg: Amazon) where all retailers can sell their products, Each Retailer will create dynamic Entity (like Products, Customers, Payments, Orders etc) , Each Entity will have millions of record each day for Each retailer

**Current System**: We are maintaining All Orders belongs to all retailers in a single collection called Orders.

**Problem**: There is a chance of getting Millions of Orders for Each retailer per Day (like Black Friday and Offer day)

**Thinking to Implement** :

- To create Individual Collection for Each Retailer (like: Retailer1_Orders, Retailer2_Orders etc..) Or
- Allow all retailers orders in a single collection with Index on RetailerId (but 1,000,000 documents per day)

**Issue**: there is a chance of 10,000 retailers and 20+ Entities, So 10000*20=200,000 collections

Is that ok to create N number of collections?
or Is that ok to save billions of documents in single collection?

Does it impact performance? and Is there any limitations for Collections count (I didn't find in MongoDocument)

**Thanks In Advance**

Comment: It is an all around bad idea to have 100K different Mongo collections.  Queyring will be a nightmare.  Instead, focus your effort on vertically (or horizontally) scaling your Mongo, adding indices, and doing things like pruning old/stale data often to keep the document count low.

Comment: Querying from application is easier as i will have RetailerInfo and EntityName, So Just need to concatenate all to get Collection Name

Comment: Is it ok to Store billions of Documents in single collection with Indexing on RetailerId? Does it effect any performance on Finding document? and we are not allowed to prune

Comment: Not being able to prune could get to be a problem.  Mongo itself limits you only on some maximum collection size (check the docs for that).

Answer (score 2):

2^(32) documents Data. If you specify a maximum number of documents for a capped collection using the max parameter to create, the limit must be less than 2^(32) documents. If you do not specify a maximum number of documents when creating a capped collection, there is no limit on the number of documents.